# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: android, android-custom-view

First of all, I know there are many questions same as mine. I have read all of them and did not find out the answer for my situation yet.

**My Situation**

I'm trying to implement `LetterAvatarView` like the Gmail. I used the [SocketIO's sample project](https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-android-chat/), and modified it's `item_message.xml` by adding the `LetterAvatarView`. Below is the result.

[image]

Here is `item_message.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/spacing">

    <com.github.nkzawa.socketio.androidchat.LetterAvatarView <--- error occur
        android:id="@+id/la_avatar"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username"
        style="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        style="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/spacing"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/spacing"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My `LetterAvatarView` class:

```
public class LetterAvatarView extends View {

    private Paint mTextPaint;
    private Paint mBackgroundPaint;
    private String[] colors = new String[]{
        "#e7e7e7", "#b6cff5", "#98d7e4", "#e3d7ff", "#fbd3e0", "#f2b2a8", "#c2c2c2", "4986e7",
            "#2da2bb", "#b99aff", "#f691b2", "#fb4c2f", "#ffc8af", "#ffdeb5", "#fbe983", "#fdedc1",
            "#b3efd3", "#a2dcc1", "#ff7537", "#ffad46", "#ebdbde", "#cca6ac", "#42d692", "#16a765"
    };
    private int radius;
    private int centerX;
    private int centerY;
    private String firstCharacter = "";

    public LetterAvatarView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public LetterAvatarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public LetterAvatarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, mBackgroundPaint);
        drawTextCentred(canvas, firstCharacter, centerX, centerY, mTextPaint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        radius = w / 2;
        centerX = w / 2;
        centerY = h / 2;
        mTextPaint.setTextSize(radius);
    }

    private void init(){
        mTextPaint = new Paint();
        mBackgroundPaint = new Paint();
        Random random = new Random();
        int backgroundColor = Color.parseColor(colors[random.nextInt(colors.length)]);
        mBackgroundPaint.setColor(backgroundColor);
        mBackgroundPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mBackgroundPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mTextPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        mTextPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mTextPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    }

    public void setText(String text){
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
            firstCharacter = text.substring(0, 1);
            firstCharacter = firstCharacter.toUpperCase();
        }
    }

    public void drawTextCentred(Canvas canvas, String text, float cx, float cy, Paint paint){
        Rect textBounds = new Rect();
        paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), textBounds);
        canvas.drawText(text, cx, cy - textBounds.exactCenterY(), paint);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1**
Here my adapter class

```
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<Message> mMessages;
private int[] mUsernameColors;

public MessageAdapter(Context context, List<Message> messages) {
    mMessages = messages;
    mUsernameColors = context.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.username_colors);
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    int layout = -1;
    switch (viewType) {
    case Message.TYPE_MESSAGE:
        layout = R.layout.item_message;
        break;
    case Message.TYPE_LOG:
        layout = R.layout.item_log;
        break;
    case Message.TYPE_ACTION:
        layout = R.layout.item_action;
        break;
    }
    View v = LayoutInflater
            .from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(layout, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    Message message = mMessages.get(position);
    viewHolder.setMessage(message.getMessage());
    viewHolder.setUsername(message.getUsername());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mMessages.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return mMessages.get(position).getType();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView mUsernameView;
    private TextView mMessageView;
    private LetterAvatarView mAvatarView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mUsernameView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
        mMessageView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.message);
        mAvatarView = (LetterAvatarView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.la_avatar);
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        if (null == mUsernameView) return;
        mUsernameView.setText(username);
        mUsernameView.setTextColor(getUsernameColor(username));
        if(mAvatarView != null) mAvatarView.setText(username);
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        if (null == mMessageView) return;
        mMessageView.setText(message);
    }

    private int getUsernameColor(String username) {
        int hash = 7;
        for (int i = 0, len = username.length(); i < len; i++) {
            hash = username.codePointAt(i) + (hash << 5) - hash;
        }
        int index = Math.abs(hash % mUsernameColors.length);
        return mUsernameColors[index];
    }
}
}
```

**UPDATE 2** `Message` class

```
public class Message {

public static final int TYPE_MESSAGE = 0;
public static final int TYPE_LOG = 1;
public static final int TYPE_ACTION = 2;

private int mType;
private String mMessage;
private String mUsername;

private Message() {}

public int getType() {
    return mType;
};

public String getMessage() {
    return mMessage;
};

public String getUsername() {
    return mUsername;
};


public static class Builder {
    private final int mType;
    private String mUsername;
    private String mMessage;

    public Builder(int type) {
        mType = type;
    }

    public Builder username(String username) {
        mUsername = username;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder message(String message) {
        mMessage = message;
        return this;
    }

    public Message build() {
        Message message = new Message();
        message.mType = mType;
        message.mUsername = mUsername;
        message.mMessage = mMessage;
        return message;
    }
}
}
```

**Problem**
My code some time work. But sometime it crashed with:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at com.github.nkzawa.socketio.androidchat.MessageAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MessageAdapter.java:39)
at com.github.nkzawa.socketio.androidchat.MessageAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MessageAdapter.java:13)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:4121)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:3431)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:3340)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1810)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1306)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1269)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:508)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:1988)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:2237)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:502)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1976)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1730)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

**How can I fix it?**

Comment: It means, you dont have a class `com.github.nkzawa.socketio.androidchat.LetterAvatarView`

Comment: @ArthurKorchagin Nope, I implemented it. See code above.

Comment: @ArthurKorchagin and it worked already. But sometime it is crashed.

Comment: Show name of package, where placed `LetterAvatarView`?

Comment: @ArthurKorchagin I told you it worked. `package com.github.nkzawa.socketio.androidchat;`

Comment: Can u show some code if MessageAdapter.java line 13 and 20?

Comment: try to clean appcompat and run it again

Comment: @StefMa I just updated my post.

Comment: @KishanSoni clean up not work.

Comment: In your onCreateViewHolder you have only three cases. When view Type isn't none of them the inflater will be inflate layout -1. Can you check if your messages have really only these types of message and not any other.

Comment: @StefMa yes, but my message type only has 3 types fit to these cases. So don't worry about that.

Comment: OK. But what if it return null in getItemViewType?

Comment: @StefMa You mean `mMessages.get(position).getType()` null?

Comment: Exactly. Try to debug it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97814/discussion-between-mr-icetea-and-stefma).

Comment: @StefMa I debugged it. It does not return null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception happens because *colors* attribute in LetterAvatarView contains an invalid rgb value.

private String[] colors = new String[]{"#e7e7e7", "#b6cff5", "#98d7e4", "#e3d7ff", "#fbd3e0", "#f2b2a8", "#c2c2c2", **"4986e7"**, "#2da2bb", "#b99aff", "#f691b2", "#fb4c2f", "#ffc8af", "#ffdeb5", "#fbe983", "#fdedc1", "#b3efd3", "#a2dcc1", "#ff7537", "#ffad46", "#ebdbde", "#cca6ac", "#42d692", "#16a765"};

```
private void init(){
        mTextPaint = new Paint();
        mBackgroundPaint = new Paint();
        Random random = new Random();
        int backgroundColor = Color.parseColor(colors[random.nextInt(colors.length)]);
        mBackgroundPaint.setColor(backgroundColor);
        mBackgroundPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mBackgroundPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mTextPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        mTextPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mTextPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    }
```

Color.parseColor(..) throws an IllegalArgumentException with some rng

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing "android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary" " with a hard coded color; 'i.e:"#212121', in all your single list items let's see the result. Also try removing "style="?android:textAppearanceMedium""...let's see if it solves it. I once had an issue like this too.

Comment: This error occur because my `LetterViewAvatar` but not `TextView`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, we can have different errors here.

The first think is that

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return mMessages.get(position).getType();
}
```

will be return 0. Don't exactly now your `Message` Object. But when `Message.TYPE_MESSAGE`, `Message.TYPE_LOG` or `Message.TYPE_ACTION` isn't 0 you will be inflate an unknown layout in `onCreateViewHolder()`.

Some code on how do you create your `List<Messages>` Object would be great.

Another problem is that you have (maybe) different layouts with differents `Views` it.
How looks your `R.layout.item_log` and `R.layout.item_action`? When they do not contain a `R.id.username`, `R.id.message` and `R.id.la_avater` it will crash too.
But I think that's another error and not really the crash here.

## Update

I've clones the source and line 39 in MessageAdapter is exactly:

```
  View v = LayoutInflater
                .from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(layout, parent, false); <-- line 39
```

I haven't found out how it can be. Because the type are set via `Message#Builder` Object.
But yes, that is the problem...

Comment: I updated my post with details of `Message` class. I checked null for `username`, and `message` in my adapter. So it can't cause the error.

Comment: Beside, I used sample project of SocketIO. It work properly until I added my `LetterAvatarView`. So I think my problem is about my custom View.

Comment: https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-android-chat here is the repository of sample project.

Comment: The jānis graumanis's answer is correct. But thank you for your enthusiastic support.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen some time when you use mipmap instead of drawable. Please check the error correctly and correct the activity xml file

I got the above error and I  correct the mipmap to drawable and it worked for me.